# Order creation adds unwanted shipping bucket

Tags: intershop

The case is following, we have a basket on which we have set only one shipping method, and which at point before order creation contains only one shipping bucket, with shipping method named "pickup".
There are 3 products in cart, two normally added products and one free gift which is added automatically with basket calculation.
This state is in pictured here:
[image]

After the order creation process (chain handlers for order creation are enabled), order contains two shipping buckets, one containing application default delivery method which is named "delivery", this is wrong and we don't want that to happen but don't know how to control it. One shipping bucket contains free gift and other contains other products. This state is displayed here:
[image]

How can we prevent having another shipping bucket being created for free gift?

EDIT: Intershop version is 7.10.15.3

Comment: Which version of icm are you on?

Comment: the free gift is placed in the bucket with the default shipping method (delivery) right?

Comment: Yes, free gift ends up in "delivery" bucket. I have also edited the question with ICM version.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce the problem on 7.10.15.2 with the standard demo shop. It is hard to say if this is a bug or a configuration problem. Can you try to reproduce this issue on an inspired demo shop?

Make sure the free gift item has the same shipping address (on line item level), shipping method and is in the same freight class as the other products.

If the problem is in the OrderCreationChain then have a look at the handlers.

Using this dev tool (only for development env)

```
/INTERSHOP/web/WFS/inSPIRED-inTRONICS-Site/en_US/-/USD/InspectHandlerChains-Start
```

There must then be a handler in that chain that creates this second bucket. Hope this helps in finding the problem.